# Sed change only in sector and remove all before pattern

Tags: linux, sed

Im stucked.
Ive got html files with:

```
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum 
Lorem ipsum 
Random text123 </td></tr></table><a name="Preamble"</a> Random text
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 123
Lorem ipsum 125
Lorem ipsum
```

I need:

```
Random text
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 123
Lorem ipsum 125
Lorem ipsum
```

I used:

```
sed 's/.*<.td><.tr><.table><a\ name\=.*><.a>//g'
```

but it cuts only chars in this line, not text before
(also i think //g is cutting all matched patterns in doc, I need only first occurence).

Second question:
Ive got huge file like:

```
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum 
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum<tag>Text that need to be changed 
Text that need to be changed by multiple seds
Text that need to be changed Text that need to be changed by multiple sed
Text that need to be changed 
Text that need to be changed </tag>Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
orem<tag>Text that need to be changed 
Text that need to be changed by multiple seds
Text that need to be changed Text that need to be changed by multiple sed
Text that need to be changed 
Text that need to be changed </tag>Lorem ipsum
```

I need to use multiple sed only on sectors started with  and ended with  how to do that?
Thanks for any reply!

Comment: Regular expressions are not meant for html or xml parsing. It's too easy to find examples where typical attempts fail. There are powerful tools for text processing in *ml files or libraries for `python`, for example. If you are sure about what you are doing, at least do things like `<a name=[^>]*>` to avoid hopping to the wrong tag end

Comment: Some html tags in a file does not make (valid) html. Your examples are bad. Try [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).